# Scrollbar scrolling in steps (html/css/jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have made a horizontal scrollbar, with products inside. But if I scroll to the right and back I can only see half product, is it possible with html/css/jquery to scroll in steps of 200px? This is the size of the width of a product photo.

Thank you for you're help.

Comment: how many products you show initially?

Comment: initially there are none to be displayed, a customer must select a type of this product category. Than there are product to be displayed, of that type. This could be 1 but could also be 20 products

Comment: yes,,, but that will be the container **width**? , and as you said it will be scrollable, so now tell me: how many products will be shown initially (if 20)... Show some code.

Comment: I used the jquery plugin below, which works very well, thank you for you're time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[jQuery.ScrollTo Plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)**

There are many ways to specify the target, including a pixel value.

Comment: @loed does it fit your needs?

Comment: It took me a while, but yes! It definitly does, thank you very much!

Comment: @xcy7e : I realise this is an old feed but a current use of this would be for parallax scrolling websites where you want to scroll between specific sections and force the end point of the scroll to be the centre position of the section.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) to scroll through your product horizontally.

This type of example may work well for you: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html

Comment: I already looked into that, but the code is programmed and ready, this requires to alter the code a lot.

Comment: Based on what you described in your post, this seems to be a good fit since you are able to scroll through and view an image as a whole. Maybe you can go into further detail on what your require?

Comment: I have fixed it with the plugin below, but thanks a lot for you're help!